# ¿Forma correctar de utilizar callbacks en un AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy tratando de obtener la respuesta del metodo **AJAX** `$.get()` fuera de la función (entorno global), pero no he podido hacerlo, utilizé **localStorage** pero este me ha traido problemas en distintas ocasiones al convertir los datos con `JSON.stringify()` y luego recibirlos con `JSON.parse()`.
La manera que estoy buscando es que pueda hacer un callback para obtenerlo, pero si lo hago desde la función del metodo `$.get("ruta", function getData())` : dice que la función está indefinida.

Ejemplo:

```
function getData(callback)
{
    $.get(ruta, function (response)
    {
        callback(response);
    })
}

var data = getData(function(response)
{
    console.log(response);
})
```

Pero incluso así tampoco seria lo correcto, porque igual estaría usando el valor dentro de otra función, la idea es tenerlo fuera de a función...

*Gracias*

Comment: ¿Necesitas, solo la respuesta de manera global o la lógica del **callback**?

Answer (score 0):

Bien, analizando tu pregunta, creo entender lo que deseas hacer. La verdad para llevar estos datos fuera de el **callback** tienes muchas opciones, por ejemplo puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
 $.get(ruta, function (res)
   {
     window.ajaxData = res
   }
 )
```

Esto llevaría los datos a una *propiedad* del *objeto* `window`, mejor dicho una **variable global** que puedes usar desde cualquier parte de tu código. Ejemplo:

```js
// Supongamos que necesitas pasar a una nueva variable, esos datos; desde cualquier parte de tu código
var newVariable = ajaxData
```

Y esto pasaria a `newVariable` los datos que guardaste de la solicitud **ajax**

---

Por otro lado si lo que necesitas es, la lógica del **callback** fuera del método [$.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) de *jQuery*. puedes hacer algo como esto:

```js
$.get(ruta, window.ajaxCallback = function (res)
   {
     window.ajaxData = res

     // Acá ira tu lógica
     // ...
   }
 )
```

Esto seria básicamente, crear una copia de esa función **callback** en otra **variable global**, en este caso `ajaxCallback`, igualmente accesible fuera de la misma. Pero claro, esto no tendría mucho sentido a menos que lo utilices en conjunto con esos datos:

```js
ajaxCallback(ajaxData)
```

O con otros datos similares a esos, todo depende de lo que necesites y/o tengas en mente